# Programmatically enable Mock Locations

Tags: android, android-intent, mocking

Is there any possible way to enable mock locations on Android without having to do it through the settings app? I would like to try and turn on Mock Locations directly from my app. So I was wondering if there is an API for that or if there was some sort of Intent I could use.

Comment: Why don't use you just hardcode coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

Prior to Marshmallow, "allow mock locations" setting could be changed programmatically (but it requires root):

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, 1);
```

So, unfortunately, the best you can do is point the user to the actual screen where the mock location app is set using the code below:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that "programmatically" unless the device is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","pm grant YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS", "settings put secure mock_location 1"});

proc.waitFor();

int value = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION);

SOP.OUT("mock_location::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: " + value);

works only on rooted device

Answer (score 0):

On Android 6+ you can run shell command `appops` to allow certain app to mock locations:

```
adb shell appops set <PACKAGE> android:mock_location allow
```

For example:

```
adb shell appops set ru.gavrikov.mocklocations android:mock_location allow
```

I'm not a developer and not sure that you can do this from within your app, but I guess running `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` with root privelege would work.